# I have a question about the C language recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, return, stack

I'm not good at English, but I'm asking you a question.
In the first row, you get the number of cards and n
You get the number of cards in the second row
At this time, I was writing a code to find the sum of the three card numbers as close to n as possible, like a black jack. I implemented this as a recursive function, and I decided that I made it all, and when I ran it, the sum would output normally, but the problem was that the sum would output over and over again. So when I did debugging, I wrote return 0; on the 14th line when I found the sum normally and output it, but it didn't end, and the recursive function kept repeating. I want to hear from you because I lack knowledge about stacks and memory and I don't know the difference between return; and return 0;. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me in detail and kindly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cards[100] = {0}, k = 0, value = 0, min = 100001, black_jack = 0;

int BlackJack(int first, int second, int third, int n, int m){
    for(int i  = third; i <= n - 1; i++){
        value = (cards[first] + cards[second] + cards[i]);
        if((m - value) < min && (m - value) >= 0){
            min = m - value;
            black_jack = value;
        }
    }
    if(first == n - 3){
        printf("%d", black_jack);
        return 0;
    }
    if(third == n - 1){
        k++;
        third = 2 + k;
        second = 1 + k;
        first += 1;
        BlackJack(first, second, third, n, m);
    }
    BlackJack(first, second + 1, third + 1, n, m);
}

int main(){
    int first = 0, second = 1, third = 2, n = 0, m = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &cards[i]);
    }
    BlackJack(first, second, third, n, m);
}
```

Comment: `return;` does not return a value, but simply goes back to the line of code after the function call. `return 0;` (or any other value) returns that value to the line of code that called the function. You should find a good C book or tutorial - the use of return is pretty basic information.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the return.  How do I get out of the recursive function on the way??

Comment: The general rule for recursive functions is that there must be a base case. If the base case is detected, the function returns without calling itself again. That should be how you get out of the recursiion.

Comment: Why is `BlackJack()` declared to return `int`? You never use the return value.

Comment: Because I'm still a beginner in C language and I thought if I do return 0; the function ends

Comment: What's base case? On the 23rd line, if(first!=n-3){
    BlackJack(first, second + 1, third + 1, n, m);
    }
Should I add the conditions like this??

Comment: @albert3289, Tip: save time. [Enable all compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/2410359).

Comment: `return` ends one function call, not several. If you want the recursion to end at a certain place you need to make sure that where you call  the recursion you also return based on that return. Eg. if you are searching the recusive call could end when the value returned is not null and keep searching otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) has two cases: the base case (where there is no recursive call) and the recursion case.

In the OP code, there are several coding issues, but at the conceptual level, it is unclear how to define the recursive function cases with the parameters of the `BlackJack` function.

Hence, I would propose a different function: `maxSum(values, nValues, nSum)` which returns the maximal sum among `nSum` values in the array `values` of size `nValues`.

The **base case** would, in fact, be two cases: (a) `nSum > nValues` (in that case, the sum cannot be formed and we return `INT_MIN` to represent an error) and (b) `nSum == 0` (in that case, the result is 0).

In the **recursive case**, we may focus on the first element of the array. The maximal sum will either include this or not. In case it is included, then the maximal sum is the first element plus the maximal sum of `nSum-1` elements in the rest of the array. In case it is not included, the maximal sum is that of `nSum` elements in the rest of the array. The overall maximal sum will be the maximal result of these 2 cases.

Putting this into code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int maxSum(int *values, int nValues, int nSum)
{
   if(nSum > nValues)
   {   // Base case (a)
       return INT_MIN;
   }
   else if(nSum == 0)
   {  // Base case (b)
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {  // Recursive case
      int result0 = values[0] + maxSum(values+1, nValues-1, nSum-1);
      int result1 = maxSum(values+1, nValues-1, nSum);
      return (result0 > result1) ? result0 : result1;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int values[] = {2, 8, 4, 7, 15};
   int result = maxSum(values, sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]), 3);
   if(result != INT_MIN)
   {
      printf("Max sum: %d\n", result);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Error!\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

One thing to notice is that this method has terrible (exponential) [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). An indication of this is when the recursive case contains more than one recursive call. In that case, it must be considered if the problem is really a hard problem or if a more efficient algorithm could be used.

In this case, the latter is true. This problem could be solved much more efficiently by e.g. sorting the array in descending order and then take the sum of the first `nSum` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for (quote) "recursive function kept repeating" seems to be missing return statements here:

```
    BlackJack(first, second, third, n, m);
}
BlackJack(first, second + 1, third + 1, n, m);
```

When/if the first of these calls of `BlackJack` returns, the execution will go on and call `BlackJack` again (i.e. the second call in the above lines). That is most likely not what you want. Instead try:

```
    return BlackJack(first, second, third, n, m);
}
return BlackJack(first, second + 1, third + 1, n, m);
```

BTW...

It's pretty hard to understand the logic for reaching the code that should terminate the recursion, i.e.

```
if(first == n - 3){
    printf("%d", black_jack);
    return 0;   <------ Stop recursion
}
```

This requires that `first` has a specific value. Looking further at you code we can see that `first` is only changed when `third` has a specific value. The value of `third` changes in two places. In one place it's a simple  increment. In the other place it depends on `k`. So when does `k` change.... well, I'm lost here. The logic is too complicated. Try to find some logic that makes it obvious that you will in fact reach the `return` statement that terminates the recursion.